# How insert data in XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I need to put some data into XML-file. I can use XmlSerializer for serializing data, but I should write data many times, so if I use XmlSerializer I get something like that

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Address xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <AddressId>0</AddressId>
   <Country>Test5</Country>
   <Region>Test5</Region>
   <Locality>Test5</Locality>
   <Street>Test5</Street>
   <HouseNumber>Test5</HouseNumber>
   <BuildingNumber>Test5</BuildingNumber>
   <ApartmentNumber>Test5</ApartmentNumber>
 </Address>

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Address xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <AddressId>0</AddressId>
   <Country>Test6</Country>
   <Region>Test6</Region>
   <Locality>Test6</Locality>
   <Street>Test6</Street>
   <HouseNumber>Test6</HouseNumber>
   <BuildingNumber>Test6</BuildingNumber>
   <ApartmentNumber>Test6</ApartmentNumber>
 </Address>
```

As you can see I have 2 root elements (?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>) because I add information in file. I can't use List because user can add information many times, so I wiil get a similar problem but with List..
  Also I knew about Linq To XML but, when I try to create a XML-file, I get an error that Xml-file didn't have a root element

```
       XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
       XElement xmlTree =
       new XElement("Addresses",
        new XElement("Address",new XAttribute("Id","1000"),                        
        new XElement("Country", address.Country),
        new XElement("Region", address.Region),
        new XElement("Locality", address.Locality),
        new XElement("Street", address.Street),
        new XElement("HouseNumber", address.HouseNumber),
         new XElement("BuildingNumber", address.BuildingNumber),
         new XElement("ApartmentNumber", address.ApartmentNumber)
         )
        );
        xmlDocument.Save("MvcApp4.xml");
```

So, what you recomend me to use for my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't add your element to your Document, and [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class doesn't belong to `LINQ to XML` you need [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
XDocument xmlDocument = new XDocument();
XElement xmlTree =
        new XElement("Addresses",
         new XElement("Address", new XAttribute("Id", "1000"),
         new XElement("Country", address.Country),
         new XElement("Region", address.Region),
         new XElement("Locality", address.Locality),
         new XElement("Street", address.Street),
         new XElement("HouseNumber", address.HouseNumber),
          new XElement("BuildingNumber", address.BuildingNumber),
          new XElement("ApartmentNumber", address.ApartmentNumber)
          )
         );
xmlDocument.Add(xmlTree);
xmlDocument.Save("MvcApp4.xml");
```

Or you could just save the `XElement` itself:

```
 xmlTree.Save("MvcApp4.xml");
```